# Setting Flask dictionary value via Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

If I was to use the following in my Jinja template:

```
{% set data['enabled'] = True %}
```

I receive the error `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token '=', got '['`. Setting one word variables is fine, but as the error states, setting dictionary values through Jinja brings an error.

Is there a workaround for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `{% set session.logged_in = True %}` ... maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja2 tries to limit assignments in its code to remove the logic from the view (check out an [MVC explanation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)).

If you still want to do an assignment you will have to use [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) with a do block. For this you have to enable [Expression Statements](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#expression-statement). After that you can try something like this:

```
{% do data.update({'enabled':'True'}) %}
```